# Triggering of JS functions on page load isn't working

Tags: javascript, onload

I have two functions that are triggered whilst the user is inputting data. They essentially add up the values of the options they choose, and output them.

On this form, in particular, the options are already pre-populated. Because of this, the functions have not been triggered, leaving their calculation as `null`.

The functions are shown just above `</body>`

**Functions:**

```
 $(calculateScore);
      function calculateScore () {
        var fields = $('.form-group #input').change(calculate);

        function calculate () {
          var score = 0;
          fields.each(function () {
            score += +$(this).val();
          });
          $('#score').html(score.toFixed(0));
        }
      }

      $(calculateHiddenScore);
      function calculateHiddenScore () {
        var fields = $('.form-group #input').change(calculate);

        function calculate () {
          var score = 0;
          fields.each(function () {
            score += +$(this).val();
          });
          $('#hidden_score').val(score.toFixed(0));
        }
      }
```

**Code placed underneath the functions to try and trigger them:**

```
$(function () {
    calculateHiddenScore();
    calculateScore();
});
```

and I have also tried:

```
window.onload = function () {
    calculateScore();
    calculateHiddenScore();
};
```

How can I trigger these two functions when the page has loaded please? Many thanks.

Comment: How are you determining that the functions are not running (as opposed to failing for some other reason)? Have you added `console.log` statements to check? Are error messages displayed on the Developer Tools Console?

Comment: I have determined they're not running because the pre-populated fields have values within them that, when added up, total > 0. If I change a dropdown option, it then triggers the functions, which result in a total > what it currently is.

Comment: Your functions are getting called. You're just not calling the ones that *they* call on `change`.

Comment: What exactly is `$(calculateScore)` and `$(calculateHiddenScore)` supposed to be doing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

DOM ready will not trigger an `onchange` event even if your items are pre-populated.
Therefore you have to modify a bit your script like:

```js
function calculateScore() {
  var fields = $('.form-group #input'); // Cache only!

  function calculate() {
    var score = 0;
    fields.each(function() {
      score += +$(this).val();
    });
    $('#score').html(score.toFixed(0));
    $('#hidden_score').val(score.toFixed(0));
  }

  calculate();                    // Calculate ASAP (on DOM ready)
  fields.on("change", calculate); // and also on change
}


jQuery(function($) { // DOM is ready and $ alias secured
  calculateScore(); // Trigger
  // other jQuery code here
});
```

P.S: BTW even if the above is a bit improved, it makes not much sense to loop using `each` over a single ID `#input` element - I'll leave that to you...